# Testing REST service in java

Tags: java, web-services, rest, testing, tdd

So, here's the thing.
There's a REST service I'm using that is supposed to be tested and I can't access the code.

I've made some kind of library in java so I can interact with that service, but I need to unit test my library (actually it's still not implemented, I'm using TDD) so I can know for sure it works.

How can I do it so I don't mess up with the service (I don't want to create nor delete anything)?
Should I use some kind of mock or stub? If so, how can it be done?

Thx!

Comment: Are you looking for code in Java to access your services or are you looking for an approach as to how to acheive this?

Comment: haha, the fact that you need to test, *after* you have built the code means you're not doing TDD!

Comment: @blo0p3r, I'd like to see an approach.

Comment: @Will, as I said, the library is still not implemented. I'm gonna use TDD but I need to know how can I test service calls without actually interacting.

Comment: My apologies!  added an answer for you instead of being glib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a mocking framework (I like [Mockito](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/)) to mock your API endpoint library. Then you can use traditional junit tests to ensure that your library is making the expected API calls.

If you want to actually make the HTTP calls, there are few other libraries you can use (Jersey client was already suggested).

Comment: I think mockito it's the thing I was looking for: a way to mock the endpoint.
As said before, I don't think I'm using Http calls...
Thx a lot!

Comment: Would you know how can I achieve my goal? I don't even know where to start >.< I don't see how can I mock the endpoint...

Comment: Mock the Java functions that make the HTTP calls, and in your mock return some hardcoded existing value. That's enough to mock out the HTTP API. Now test your program as you normally would.

Answer (score 3):

I use the [Jersey test framework](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/test-framework.html) to test - if you have written your code with Jersey.  It runs grizzly in the background.

You could use HttpUnit's PseudoServer to create fake responses.

Or you could use [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi) to generate post and get requests to your running service.

Comment: Jersey sounds good, but I'm conditioning the whole app to Jersey... I think it doesn't fit in this project.
And httpClient would actually make the requests and that's exactly what I need to avoid.
Thx for the reply!

Answer (score 1):

Is [rest assured](http://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/) a thing you wanted to find?

Answer (score 0):

My organization uses spring to generate our mock rest services. [Spring MVC test framework (formally spring social test)](http://blog.springsource.org/2012/11/12/spring-framework-3-2-rc1-spring-mvc-test-framework/) works very well. However if you aren't already using spring i'd suggest Jmock, mockito, or easy mock to just fake a response.

Answer (score 0):

I dislike the idea to use a mock since it leaves out the HTTP stuff. Best is using a mock server like [enter link description here](http://mock-server.com). It is a bit tricky first but once you have your test case up and running it is a breeze. I use random ports to start the mock server so one can run tests in parallel.